# Check if value exists in range without looping

Tags: vba, excel

I'm used to python syntax where to check if `7` is in `list1` you simply type `7 in list1` and it returns a boolean. How can I perform something like this in vba?

I'm currently looping through a large range.  I want to occasionally check if a value i'm looping over is in a different range.  This could get much slower if I had to nest more loops into my loops.  What's the fastest way to approach this problem?

```
For i = 400 To 1 Step -1:
'doing other things

'here's some psuedo-code of what I want to do
If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("NamedRange")
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next i
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend collecting the entire list in memory if it's already in the worksheet. If this is a one-off, I would recommend using some formulas and then some filters (or even pivot tables could quickly find what you're looking for). If you need to do this over and over - needing automation - then can you please share some more info? Like what you intend to do with the matches you find?

Comment: @joseph4tw, added more context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a countif, if it's greater than zero then you know it exists in the list:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("NamedRange"), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value) > 0 Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: This definitely worked out for me so I marked it as answered but now I'm realizing how slow it is.  What takes less than a second takes about 7 seconds to execute. Can you think of an even faster way?

Comment: It's probably the delete taking the time, is there a large number of formulas in the sheet? You could set `Application.calculation = XLCalculationManual` at the start then back to XLCalculationAutomatic at the end, this will make it only calculate once all the deletes are finished.

Comment: Wow, you responded so fast. I actually just realized I'm being a dummy for counting the named range all 400 times. I really only need to do it infrequently so I applied a simple if conditional to make it execute a LOT less times.  Thanks for the tip about calcs, I just added that to my code.

Comment: No probs, let me know what sort of a performance boost you get :). I have the SO app on my phone so it vibrates to alert me, hence my quick response ;)

Comment: Well, the major lag was because it was counting the named range all 400 times. It'll really only need to do it a max of 50 times and usually a lot less I think.  That's where my 7 seconds went. I don't know if there's a difference with the manual calcs turned off. It's imperceptible to me if there is

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve it in just one line

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(ValueToSearchFor, RangeToSearchIn, 0)) Then
// Value found
End If
```

**Example:**
Search for Blah-Blah in column A of Sheet5

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match("Blah-Blah", Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
   'The value present in that range
End If
```