# How can I correct my VBA Code for a type 13 error mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

```
Sub WorksheetChange()
'declare a variable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foundation Budget Template")
'calculate if a cell contains text, using the ISNUMBER function, and then return a specified value
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ws.Range("A1:A100")) = False Then
ws.Range("C1:C100") = "Contains Text"
Else

ws.Range("C1:C100") = "No Text"
End If
End Sub
```

I keep getting a type mismatch 13 error. I am not sure where my types fail but I want to find out! This vba code is for Scanning column A and if Column A is a number then post "contains text" otherwise if A is not a number post "no text" in column C.

Comment: Run-time error '13' Type mismatch. Sorry English is not my first language.

Comment: Probably easiest to use a loop.

Comment: you cannot compare an array of items to a single value.  Loop it and compare one at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if value exists in range without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714043/check-if-value-exists-in-range-without-looping)

Comment: `ws.Range("C1:C100") = ws.Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A100),""No Text"",""Contains Text"")")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub WorksheetChange()
    
    'declare a variable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim row As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    'calculate if a cell contains text, using the ISNUMBER function, and then return a specified value
    For row = 1 To 100
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ws.Cells(row, 1)) = False Then
            ws.Cells(row, 3) = "Contains Text"
        Else
            ws.Cells(row, 3) = "No Text"
        End If
    Next row
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to improve upon it so I added        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ws.Cells(row, 1)) = False And ws.Cells(row, 3) = "" Then
            ws.Cells(row, 3) = "0"
            
        Else
            ws.Cells(row, 3) = ws.Cells(row, 3). So that if A is a number and C is blank then Display 0 else default to whatever C's value was.